# Nested repeater - Access item count in parent repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET and I'm working on converting some pages from ColdFusion to .NET and C#. In ColdFusion I'm doing nested looping through record sets, schedules and schedule details, creating a table for each schedule with its details and hiding all but the active table. When rendering the tables, I'm creating the navigation mechanism in the first row of the table, which will show the previous or next table and hide the current one (via jQuery):

```
<< 07/15/2019 - 07/22/2019 >>    
[schedule details rows]
```

This is trivial in Coldfusion, but I've spent hours trying to duplicate this in ASP.NET with no success. I need to know the total item count (the number of parent records) and conditionally render the chevrons accordingly depending if I'm on the first, last or in between record.

I've tried using a session variable, In the code behind:

```
int count = repScheduleDates.Items.Count;
Session["scheduleDatesCount"] = count;

Debug.WriteLine("Session[scheduleDatesCount]: " + Session["scheduleDatesCount"]);
```

If I have 2 records, the debug print will show 2. However, in the the aspx file

```
<%#Session["scheduleDatesCount"]%>
```

shows nothing (not 0; just no output).

If I do this in the aspx:

```
<%# repScheduleDates.Items.Count %>
```

it shows the *current* item number; 0 or 1, NOT the total count.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="repScheduleDates">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table style="border:1px solid #0000FF;">  
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="background-color:#FF6600; color:#000000; font-size: large;">  
                    <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="6">
                        <%-- I need a conditional statement here to add the appropriate class if first record or not --%>
                        <i id="leftNav_<%#Container.ItemIndex%>" class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> 
                            <%#Eval("schStartDate") %> - <%#Eval("schEndDate") %>
                        <%-- I need a conditional statement here to add the appropriate class if last record or not --%>
                        <i id="rightNav_<%#Container.ItemIndex%>" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> 
                    </td>  
                </tr>
                [more parent stuff...]
                <asp:Repeater id="repScheduleDetails" runat="server" OnDataBinding="repScheduleDetails_DataBinding">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        [output child stuff...]                 
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>      
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

How can I get the total count of the items in the parent repeater?

Comment: Did you check the value before or after the evaluation of the repeater.  To each page I am sure there is a flow and if you try to get the value of that session variable before it is ever set then it will be nothing.  Try checking it later in the page perhaps.

Comment: I don't get it; I get nothing after the repeater as well (although it wouldn't do me any good even if I could).

Comment: Wouldn't you know the number of rows/items of the collection you are binding to the Repeater? Like a DataTable or List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%#Session["scheduleDatesCount"]%>
```

This will not show the record.

Either use

```
<%=Session["scheduleDatesCount"]%>
```

Or Create Public variable count on .cs page and show on aspx page like

```
<%=count%>
```